# How is the 'Algebraic Degree' calculated in the paper about analysing the white-box AES(Chow et al. 2002) by exploiting internal collisions?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, symmetric, white-box, bijection

[This paper](https://books.google.co.kr/books?hl=en&lr=&id=n825BQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA265&ots=PKSFmvJNak&sig=PTNUktsiYRdxuaGudgxuRxeSZho&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) proposed a new attack on the initial white-box AES implementation of Chow *et al*.

> In order to determine the good solution, we use the
> particular structure of the function $S_{0}$.
>
> $S^{-1} \circ S_{0} \left( \cdot \right) = P_{0}\left( \cdot \right)\oplus k_{0} $
>
> By definition of $P_{0}$, the above
> function has algebraic degree at most 4.

According to this paper, $P_{0}$ denotes bijective mapping on the vector space $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{8}$, which is the combination of two 4-bit input encodings and one 8 $\times $ 8-bit mixing bijection.

Given the next proposed `Lemma 2` in this paper, I know the `algebraic degree` is about boolean function, then I study the boolean function and high-order derivations of [Lai 1994](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Xuejia_Lai/publication/246375728_Higher_Order_Derivatives_and_Differential_Cryptanalysis/links/5729996908aef7c7e2c0d7bf.pdf).

But I still can't understand why the algebraic degree at most 4 by definition of $P_{0}$?

Comment: give a loook here: https://www.paris.inria.fr/secret/Anne.Canteaut/poly.pdf on how the degree is computed. (chapter 1, page 5 to 8, there is an example)